# Garmin prototype.js conflicts with local jquery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, garmin

I have prototype.js from Garmin which conflicts with my jquery.frm.js as written in the code snippet below.

```
<script src="/public/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/jquery.frm.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://developer.garmin.com/web/communicator-api/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
```

It would throw an error 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - jquery.frm.js
Here is a small snippet of jquery.frm.js code (since it's too long!)

```
var FRAMEWORK_PREFIX = "erpFrm";
(function( $ ){

$.frm = {
    priorityAccepted : new Array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
    initFunctions : new Array(),
    _isLoading : false,

    /*
     *   Pagination Variables
     */
    currentPage : 0,
    itemsPerPage: 100,
    paginationOffset: 3,
    /*
     * Use to define fast ffward
     */
    pace: 6,
    options: {},
    show: true,




    /**
     * Init function to run page is loaded
     * @returns {undefined}
     */
    init : function() {
        for(var i=0; i < this.initFunctions.length; i++) {
            this.initFunctions[i].callback();
        }
        return this;

    } ....
})( jQuery );

$(document).ready(function() {
    try {
        $.frm.init(); 
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
        $.frm.showPopup(e.message);
    }

});
```

Actually document.ready does not execute! How can this be?

Basically I tried 2 solutions - which both should load the scripts and codes inside the jquery.frm.js that is why I call the script inside the function or after noConflict

First Solution

```
<script>
    (function($) {
        $.getScript('/public/js/jquery.frm.js').done(function(script, textStatus) {
           console.log(textStatus);
        }).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
           console.log(exception);
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

This code would still return the same error - undefined is not a function

Second Solution

```
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $.getScript('/public/js/jquery.frm.js').done(function(script, textStatus) {
            console.log(textStatus);
        }).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
            console.log(exception);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Still same error persists.

Please give me some insights on how to fix the problem please.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an aliase of the jQuery and use in your script. The example code below I taken from the [jquery official website](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). Hope this should resolve your issue.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

// Do something with jQuery
j( "div p" ).hide();

// Do something with another library's $()
$( "content" ).style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your script code, use `jQuery.noConflict()` to release the `$` back for other scripts to use, in this case the prototype.js code. See the jQuery noConflict docs for details: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/.

(begin personal opinion) I don't recommend simply assigning jQuery to another short alias. These JavaScript aliases that everybody wants to use are just like really short, bad variable names. Most developers would recommend avoiding variable names like 'x' and 'y' in most cases, especially if the variable has a very large scope. Using '$' or 'j' for jQuery makes your source shorter, but is that really that important. Just run the code through a minimizer before using it in production. (end personal opinion)